# How does Boost serialize STL containers?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I need to know how Boost::Serialize works with STL containers - such as map, vector and list.

Specifically, does it saves the size of the entire container right before all the actual container data itself?

Can I read that size in order to know how large the STL container is?

I am on Win7, 64bit with Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the source code for boost serializing `std::vector`s: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/boost/serialization/vector.hpp

`std::set`s: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/boost/serialization/set.hpp

`std::list`s: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/boost/serialization/list.hpp

`std::vector` is pretty clear that it does.  If you look in the http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/boost/serialization/collections_load_imp.hpp implementation header file we see:

```
collection_size_type count;
//...
ar >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(count);
```

in the `load_collection` function.  Both `std::list` and `std::set` serializer calls this directly.